# How do I update banshee to 2.4?

Tags: banshee

I currently have Banshee 2.2.1 and I want 2.4 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa` in Terminal, followed by:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

But Banshee is still not updated to 2.4.  I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove banshee
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

and that gets me back to version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You've run the commands the wrong way around. `apt-get update` should be first (it updates your computer's list of what software is available) and then `apt-get upgrade` (upgrades the packages installed).

In short, just run `sudo apt-get upgrade` again, or open Update Manager.

---

**Edit** I've just noticed that I'm not using this PPA, I'm using the daily-builds version `ppa:banshee-team/banshee-daily`. There is an inherently higher chance that there'll be a significant bug one day but it has worked for me so far:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/banshee-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or you can stick with the release PPA and wait for somebody to fix the `libmono-upnp-cil-dev` dependency issue (that fossfreedom points out).

Comment: Thank you, I have just tried what you suggested but I am still with 2.2.1... The update manager only lets me go to 2.2.1 as well.

Comment: It takes a couple of hours for a newly added packages in a PPA to appear when you try to upgrade from it. It has been only 5 to 6 hours. Wait about 12 more. In my case it was with Wine and it was about 24 hours that I had to wait.

Answer (score 2):

## 12.04/11.10

As of this evening 22 March 2012, the AMD64 and i386 builds for Oneiric have successfully built. Previous to this, the builds failed and hence were probably the initial cause of your issue.  A similar build issue exists for Natty and Maverick.

You can install this as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Occasionally, running a `update & upgrade` does not pull in the newer PPA version. The package manage gets its upset for some strange reason.

Usually I find that in these circumstances you can force this by first purging your current install, updating and then reinstalling.

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get purge banshee
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Even more rarely you may have to ppa-purge the PPA itself, purging and then readding the PPA.

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:banshee-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge banshee
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom, I did the procedure for 2.4/11.10 and th