# Updating Banshee to 2.4

Tags: banshee

I have banshee 2.2.1 with Ubuntu 11.10 
I have been trying to update banshee to 2.4 (released yesterday) but it just isnt working, I have been using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
```

in terminal, from the Banshee.fm website. but after running through terminal it says this:

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 PPA for Banshee Team
 This PPA contains the latest stable debs of Banshee for Ubuntu. To install Banshee, you must first enable the PPA on your system:
1. Open Software Sources (System->Administration->Software Sources)
2. Navigate to the "Third Party Sources" tab. 
3. Click "Add"
4. Enter the APT line below that corresponds to your Ubuntu version that starts with "deb".
5. Click "Add Source"
6. Click "Close"
7. It will prompt you to reload your software cache. Click "Reload".
8. Now install the package "banshee" from Synaptic, or using the command below:
sudo apt-get install banshee

For those who wish to compile from trunk, add the deb-src line and then run "sudo apt-get build-dep" to install all required dependencies before starting to compile.

Unstable (version which have odd minor version numbers) debs of Banshee can be found here:
https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/banshee-unstable
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~banshee-team/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.OPAjxemDQr --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 9D2C2E0A3C88DD807EC787D74874D3686E80C6B7
gpg: requesting key 6E80C6B7 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 6E80C6B7: "Launchpad PPA for Banshee Team" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I believe I have the ppa but, im not sure. I need a step by step process to get this, ive been trying to figure it out for quite a while now...

Comment: Try this thread, I just asked a similar question:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/115083/how-do-i-update-banshee-to-2-4

Answer (score 2):

You've added the PPA but that doesn't automatically update or upgrade anything.

You  just need to update with Update Manager or via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```