# Missing ppa-purge Package?

Tags: installation, 10.04, package-management

I want to upgrade Banshee from version 2.0 to 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.  When I run sudo apt-get install ppa-purge I get the error message

E: Couldn't find package ppa-purge.

I am following instructions given in

[How do I update banshee to 2.4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115083/how-do-i-update-banshee-to-2-4)

Thanks!

Lou

Comment: I followed your instructions, and version 2.0 of Banshee was downgraded to version 1.6 instead of being upgraded to 2.6 What do you recommend now? Lou

Comment: This is another question - remember to register your account so that you dont have to keep creating new accounts.  ppa-purge downgrades your version. That is its purpose.  Since what you have posted is not an answer - this has been removed and has been instead converted to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a command for 11.10+ for 10.04. That might work but more than often does not.

Looking at the packages on ubuntu.com `ppa-purge` can be found in `lucid-backports` and not in `lucid`: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-backports/utils/ppa-purge  So you need to [add the backports to your sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). Please read the wiki page thoroughly. Enabling Backports Manually can be done by adding the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

After that a (one time)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should update your resource and the `apt-get install ppa-purge` should work on your system too.